# Python incorrect ways to add to list when generating permutations

Tags: python

In this example, why does this generate the correct result:

```
nxt = path + [nums[i]]
```

But not:

```
nxt = path ; nxt += [nums[i]]
```

```
nxt = path ; nxt.append(nums[i])
```

```
def permute(nums):
    def dfs(nums, path):
      if not nums: # empty, done with path
          all_perms.append(path)
          return

      for i in range(len(nums)):
        nxt = path + [nums[i]]
        # nxt = path ; nxt += [nums[i]]
        # nxt = path ; nxt.append(nums[i])
        print(nxt)
        dfs(nums[:i] + nums[i+1:], nxt)

    all_perms = []
    dfs(nums, [])
    return all_perms
```

Comment: Because `path + [nums[i]]` creates a **new** list, while doing `nxt = path` is just another reference to the same list, so modifying `nxt` will be reflected on `path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this example, why does this generate the correct result:
>
> ```
> nxt = path + [nums[i]]
> ```

This leaves `path` unmodified.

> But not:
>
> ```
> nxt = path ; nxt += [nums[i]]
> ```
>
> ```
> nxt = path ; nxt.append(nums[i])
> ```

This appends `nums[i]` to `path` which is apparently incorrect.